# How do I create a Document scoped bookmark to be saved to a new Document?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I have a sandboxed Document based Mac application. My Documents incorporate images on users machines. I want to save a document-scoped bookmark to an image used in my document so that I have access to the image when I close and reopen the Document.

Here is how I create a bookmark:

```
 //path is path to an image
 //for a new document docUrl is set to the location where we will save our document
 NSURL * pathUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
 NSError * error;
 NSData * pathBookmarkData = [pathUrl bookmarkDataWithOptions:
                              (NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope 
                             | NSURLBookmarkCreationSecurityScopeAllowOnlyReadAccess)
                              includingResourceValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLPathKey] 
                             relativeToURL:docUrl error:&error];
```

this results in following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Untitled.mydocext” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." (Collection URL points to a file that doesn't exist) UserInfo=0x608000070800 {NSURL=file:///Users/myname/Pictures/Untitled.mydocext, NSDebugDescription=Collection URL points to a file that doesn't exist}
```

How do I create a document scoped bookmark to be saved to a new document?

Here is how I get path:

```
NSArray* fileTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"png", @"jpg", @"jpeg", @"bmp", @"gif", @"tif", @"tiff", @"PNG", @"JPG", @"JPEG", @"BMP", @"GIF", @"TIF", @"TIFF", nil];

NSOpenPanel *panel;

panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[panel setTitle:@"Select Photos"];

[panel setFloatingPanel:YES];

[panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[panel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];

[panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        NSMutableArray * pathsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSArray * urlArray = [panel URLs];
        for (NSURL * url in urlArray) {
            //this is how I get path to image, assume I am not selecting directories
            NSString * path = [url path];
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: How did you obtain 'path'? The preferred way would be to use a NSOpenPanel to get a security scoped URL or user drops image into your app.

Comment: I delay obtaining a security scoped bookmark, until the user tries to save my document for the first time. This is when, I get the location where I will save the document and hence relativeURL to use in bookmarkDataWithOptions:includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeToURL:error: function to obtain a document scoped bookmark.

Comment: @AmaltasCoder did you ever solve this problem? I'm trying to do the same thing, but various bugs in OSX prevent me from correctly/reliably saving a document with document scoped bookmarks inside them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to delay the creation of SSB. Also the transfer to path and then to URL back might cause some problems with the sandbox. Try using something along following:

```
    // the URLs come back with access to it. they are added to the sandbox by the panel. no need to do anything like start accessing security scoped.
    NSArray * urlArray = [panel URLs];

    for (NSURL *urlToStore in urlArray) {
        // create a SSB out of the URL
        NSError *erroer = nil;
        NSData *bookmarkData = nil;
        bookmarkData = [urlToStore bookmarkDataWithOptions:(NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope| NSURLBookmarkCreationSecurityScopeAllowOnlyReadAccess)
                            includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil
                                             relativeToURL:docUrl
                                                     error:&erroer];
        if (erroer) {
            NSLog(@"couldn't create NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope with error: %@", [erroer description]);
        } else if ( bookmarkData ) {
            // store the bookmark data either in the document or internally for later persistency
        } else {
            NSLog(@"no error and no bookmarkData: %@", [self description]);
        }
     }
```